# Dynamic keyword with database value

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this:

```
class meter1(models.Model):
    U1N = models.FloatField(default=0)
    U2N = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

In my view (simplified) I want to set the value for the database dynamically:

```
def import_data:
    dict = {"1":"U1N","2":"U2N",}
    c = "1"
    q = meter1()
    q.eval('dict[c]') = "1"
    q.save()
```

In real `dict` contains 60 items, and `c` changes every time in a for loop. The code in this example results in an error: `NameError: name 'U1N' is not defined.`

How do I dynamically set the keyword for q?

Comment: What about `setattr`?

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you. I was stuck with eval() and overlooked setattr. +1 for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setattr` to dynamically set attributes to the objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can also dynamically build a dict from your `dict` (you shouldn't use a builtin name as identifier BTW) and pass it as kwargs to `meter1()` (you shouldn't use all-lowers as class names BTW). Oh and yes: you may want to have a look at `modelmanager.create()` too.

```
def import_data():
    fieldmap = {"1":"U1N","2":"U2N",}
    fieldindex = "1"
    kw = {fieldmap[fieldindex]: 1.0}

    # either:
    q = Meter1(**kw)
    q.save()

    # or:
    q = Meter1.objects.create(**kw)
```

Comment: Thank you for the hints! I will look into them +1